# Cin not getting the proper input

Tags: c++, cin

I have an issue with a program I'm writing in C++. Note that I am not on my laptop (I'm at work for the next 8 hours) so I can't copy the code here but I've spent a few hours on this issue so I know what is wrong, just don't know how to fix it. So my code looks something like this :

```
bool valid = false;
int choice;

cout << "Please make a choice between 1 and 4\n"; 
//Here I enumarate 4 choices
cin >> choice;  //first input

//note that I do verify that an integer is entered and that it's between 1 and 4
//my code works so far

valid = true; //if the choise is good

while(valid)
{
     if (choice == 1)
     {
         //here I open a url
         cout << "If you would like to stick with this choice, presse 1 again or make  another choice \n";

         //This is where the code does not work at all
         cin >> choice; //second input

         if (choice == 1) //this line is to get out of the loop but I never reach it
             valid = false;
     }
     if (choice == 2) //contains similar code to the 1st if
     {
     }
     if (choice == 3) //contains similar code to the 1st if
     {
     }
     if (choice == 4) //contains similar code to the 1st if
     {
     }
     else
     {
          cout << "This is not one the choices. Choose again!";
          cin >> choice;
     }
}
```

I've only filled out the first if when the user chooses the 1st option since the 3 other if behave the same way, just with a different link. Here's how the program behaves when the user chooses the 1st option. It opens the link just fine and then it asks the user to press 1 again to stick with this option or make another choice. It ALWAYS goes into the else condition afterwords. Even if I presss 1 to get out of the loop, it goes into the else. That means whatever input I typed, it was not registered as an integer between 1 and 4.

I've tried debugging to see what value "choice" has after the 2nd input and it shows 49! Which makes no sense since I typed 1. However, after the else, if I make a correct choice between 1 and 4, for example 1, the link will open again just fine and the program will once again ask me to press 1 to stick with my choice or make another choice.

I assume there is still something on the buffer. I read a little about it to understand how to clear it but I've tried cin.clear(), cin.ignore(), cin.sync() after the first cin but the second input is always different than what I actually typed and no matter what I type, it will go into the else once again. It's an infinite loop from hell.

I'm still new at c++ and I'm trying a few ideas. I tried solving this by myself but I need help. Thank you.

Comment: Note: Even you 'verify that an integer is entered and that it's between 1 and 4' you never check the stream state, which is totally wrong.

Comment: the stream state? Could you elaborate? You can just tell me what I need to read and I'll do it.

Comment: @Davel Try an input 'hello' and debug

Comment: 49 is the ASCII code for the character '1', so perhaps `cin >> choice` is reading the input as a character instead of as an integer value. Not clear why you would only notice this on the second `>>`, however. I try never to use `cin >>` for input, so that's about as much as I can say about this.

Comment: You do reach the line that says  "I never reach it", however you then fall down to the other `if` cases

Comment: When I entered 2, I remember it showed 50 as the value of `choice` so it must be ASCII code. Would it be better to use `cin.get()`?

Comment: I just want to let you know that it works now. Thank you. The issue was the `else if`.

Comment: The problem about the `cin` not working is that after I opened the link, I had to presse ENTER in console, otherwise the `cin` registers whatever I type and converts it in Ascii code. So if I did not press enter after opening the link, when I type 1 I would get 49 as the value of `choice`(I tried with other numbers too) but if I did press enter, I would get 1 as the value of `choice`. Now don't ask me why it does that I don't know. The command I use to open a link is ShellExecute if you want to know.

Answer (score 2):

```
//Your control block was not correct. 
//Your logic falls into the else block after the second input 
//has been read because it use the new value of choice and run through all the
//if statements. In a case where you have multiple options in that manner use 'else if'` 

void start()
{
    bool valid = false;
    int choice;

    cout << "Please make a choice between 1 and 4\n"; 
    //Here I enumarate 4 choices
    cin >> choice;  //first input

    //note that I do verify that an integer is entered and that it's between 1 and 4
    //my code works so far

    valid = true; //if the choise is good

    while(valid)
    {
         if (choice == 1)
         {
             //here I open a url
             cout << "If you would like to stick with this choice, presse 1 again or make  another       choice \n";

             //This is where the code does not work at all
             cin >> choice; //second input

             if (choice == 1)
             {
                valid = false;
             } //this line is to get out of the loop but I never reach it

         }

         else if (choice == 2) //contains similar code to the 1st if
         {
         }
         else if (choice == 3) //contains similar code to the 1st if
         {
         }
         else if (choice == 4) //contains similar code to the 1st if
         {
         }
         else
         {
              cout << "This is not one the choices. Choose again!";
              cin >> choice;
         }
    }   
}
int main(void)
{
    start();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: thank you, I will try that when I get home (in 7 hours) but I have a question? don't you think it's odd that it doesn't read this : `if (choice == 1){ valid = false;}`

Comment: It read it! The second time the user is prompted choice has a new value then your program checks all the other 'if' blocks and compare against that value. As a result if the new value of the variable 'choice' does not correspond with any of the values in the 'if' statements then it will always fall in the else block.

Comment: Thank you. This was the solution.

Answer (score 0):

As Codec has stated, your `if else` is incorrect, after you confirm your choice, it will compare your choice to the value of 2, 3 and 4. Since it is 1 now, it will get to the else statement and execute whatever in there. My suggestion is to use switch statement, which will be a lot easier to read.

```
cin >> choice;

switch(choice)
{
    case 1:
    // do whatever you want
    break;
    case 2:
    // do whatever you want
    break;
    // continue with your choice
    default:
    // do whatever you want if the value falls out of your choice
    cout << "This is not the right choice" << endl;
    break;
}
```

Comment: I thought of that. The reason is that I want the user to confirm his choice or make another choice. I could put the switch into a loop. Ok, if the `if else` works I'll switch to this. Thank you.

Answer (score -2):

In your while loop use as this:

```
while(valid)
   {
    if(choice==1)
      {
        //your code
      }
else if(choice==2)
      {
       //your code
      }
else if(choice==3)
      {
       //your code
      }
else if(choice==4)
      {
       //your code
      }
else 
      {
       //your code
      }
}
```

Comment: I checked the code after correction, it worked fine. Was not logically wrong after correction. That's the only fault he's done due to which he's not getting the result he's expecting. BTW have you checked the code once?

Comment: I've checked. And he clearly states that the problem is in the value of choice variable after `cin`. The logic may be flawed (or as he says, he's in work and he wrote it fast so the 'original' code may be ok), but it doesn't change the fact that after inputting 1 he get's 49

Comment: Could you elaborate on this answer a bit? Code only answers are usually discouraged.

Comment: @prajmus exactly my point. Even if I enter `cout << choice` right after the 2nd input it will show 49.

Comment: I don't know about the 49, but this answer is correct insofar as the code should be using `if...else if...else if`. As it stands, you're hitting the `else` clause for any value other than 4, which is not what you intended. What is telling you 49? Try a print statement in the `else` clause.

Comment: Thank you. This was the solution.

Comment: The problem about the `cin` not working is that after I opened the link, I had to presse ENTER in console, otherwise the `cin` registers whatever I type and converts it in Ascii code. So if I did not press enter after opening the link, when I type 1 I would get 49 as the value of `choice`(I tried with other numbers too) but if I did press enter, I would get 1 as the value of `choice`. Now don't ask me why it does that I don't know. The command I use to open a link is ShellExecute if you want to know.